# Xamarin form vs native

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin mobile app development. I have researched on google and I got to know we can develop mobile apps in two ways.

1. Using form
2. Native

I am figuring out applications (live) on apple store which are developed in form and native. But I am not able to get apps.

Can you please give me some reference app which has been developed using form and native. So I can check the difference between the two platforms.

Comment: Could you please mark my aswer as correct if it is for you?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think that there is an app out there that is implemented both ways. Would be a lot of extra work without any benefit. 
You should have a look on what you want your app to do, and then decide yourself how to implement it. Here's what Xamarin tells you ([Xamarin Forms](https://www.xamarin.com/forms#choose-an-approach)):

Xamarin.Forms:

- Apps that require little platform-specific functionality
- Apps where code sharing is more important than custom UI
- Developers comfortable with XAML

Xamarin.Android & Xamarin.iOS:

- Apps with interactions that require native behavior
- Apps that use many platform-specific APIs
- Apps where custom UI is more important than code sharing